# Apply the definition of a limit of a function to determine $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^{a} $ where $ a \in \mathbb{R} $ is positive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

As stated above.

I know how to verify the existence of a limit, but have no idea how to find the limit,
any ideas?

Is this sufficient?

Using the definition of convergence when $x = 0 $ we get $ \left | L \right | < \varepsilon $. Therefore   $ \left | L \right | > 0 $ but never smaller than $0$. So $0$ is the limit?

Comment: How about letting $x=0$, given that you can't have an indeterminate form? Then you should be able to verify the limit.

Comment: So simply $ \left | L \right | < \varepsilon $ at $ x = 0 $ Therefore $ \left | L \right | > 0 $ but never smaller than $0$. So $0$ is the limit?

Comment: $0$ is the limit and thus you have to solve $\lvert x^a \rvert <\varepsilon$.

Comment: You will need a definition of $x^a$.  I like the definition $x^a=\exp(a\log x)$, but maybe you prefer a different one.